# Remove or offset the translucent black overlay when UI Search Display Controller becomes active

Tags: uisearchbar, ios7, uisearchdisplaycontroller

How can I remove the overlay that is shown by Search Display Controller or offset it in iOS7. The bug is only for iOS7. Apple developer forum is not very helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me:

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: YES animated: YES];
    //...
}


-(void)searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: NO animated: YES];
    //...
}
```